# return in class-based components use different brackets

Tags: reactjs

I used `create-react-app` to set up the workspace. I was trying to use a button to increment the number shown on the page. I added event handler to the button which will increment. I defined the function as a class function and then I got a strange behavior by the `return` function. When used inside class function it uses `{}`, when used inside the render method it uses `()`.

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };

    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { count: prevState.count + 1 };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Didnt exactly get, what you are trying to ask?

Comment: I would strongly recommend taking a basic JavaScript tutorial, you need a solid grasp of the syntax to move up to React. You can `return` lots of different things including, as in those two examples, objects or React elements (created from JSX). You can also wrap lots of different things in parentheses; you could also put parentheses around an object: `return ({ ...`. It's also not a function, note you don't invoke it using parentheses; it's a statement:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with React, but JavaScript syntax itself. Return is not really a function call.

When you do:

```
return (1)
```

It is the exact same as

```
return 1
```

The curly brackets are used to create an object. For example:

```
return { a: 1 }
```

Will return an object with a key called a which has the value 1.

The following are the same:

```
return { a: 1 }
```

And

```
let obj = { a: 1 }
return obj
```

You see that the curly brackets have nothing to do with the return statement, but rather to create the object.

As others have noted, learn more about JavaScript fundamentals before moving to React.